# Excel VBA .find works on first macro run but not second

Tags: excel, vba

I open my workbook and run my macro and all code (that I can tell) executes fine. Without changing any data I try and run the macro again and I get an error. The error specifically happens with `.Find` and is returning `Nothing` when in fact there is a date to be found in the specified range.

I have gone through the debug tool and by all accounts I do not know why `.Find` is returning `Nothing` on the second Macro run and not the first.

The line in question is:

```
Set DateFind = .Find(what:=TripFind.Offset(0, 2).Value, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                     MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

The first time running the Macro `DateFind` Returns the correct value. The second time the Macro is run `DateFind` Returns `Nothing` but on all accounts should be returning the same value as on the first run of the Macro.

Here is the full code section that is in question:
**The first part of the code runs fine. The second part starting at 'Adds day numbers... etc. is the important part.*

```
ElseIf TripCal.Range("A1") = "SESSION 2" Then

        '-----Copies and pastes cabin numbers into tripcal-----
    For TotalRowsOffered = 5 To 168
        If TotalRowsOffered >= Level1Offered And TotalRowsOffered < Level2Offered And TripsOffered.Cells(TotalRowsOffered, Session2) <> "" Then
            a = TotalRowsOffered - 6
            TripCal.Cells(TotalRowsOffered + a, "B") = TripsOffered.Cells(TotalRowsOffered, Session2).Value
        ElseIf TotalRowsOffered >= Level2Offered And TotalRowsOffered < Level3Offered And TripsOffered.Cells(TotalRowsOffered, Session2) <> "" Then
            a = TotalRowsOffered - 8
            TripCal.Cells(TotalRowsOffered + a, "B") = TripsOffered.Cells(TotalRowsOffered, Session2).Value
        ElseIf TotalRowsOffered >= Level3Offered And TotalRowsOffered < Level4Offered And TripsOffered.Cells(TotalRowsOffered, Session2) <> "" Then
            a = TotalRowsOffered - 10
            TripCal.Cells(TotalRowsOffered + a, "B") = TripsOffered.Cells(TotalRowsOffered, Session2).Value
        ElseIf TotalRowsOffered >= Level4Offered And TotalRowsOffered < Level5Offered And TripsOffered.Cells(TotalRowsOffered, Session2) <> "" Then
            a = TotalRowsOffered - 12
            TripCal.Cells(TotalRowsOffered + a, "B") = TripsOffered.Cells(TotalRowsOffered, Session2).Value
        ElseIf TotalRowsOffered >= Level5Offered And TripsOffered.Cells(TotalRowsOffered, Session2) <> "" Then
            a = TotalRowsOffered - 14
            TripCal.Cells(TotalRowsOffered + a, "B") = TripsOffered.Cells(TotalRowsOffered, Session2).Value
        End If
    Next

        '-----Adds day number of trip for each cabin-----
    For TripCounter = 4 To 323
        If TripCal.Cells(TripCounter, "B") = "" Then
                'Skips if there is no trip name accounted for _
                 beside the level on the Trip Calender
        Else
            With TripsOffered.Range(TripsOffered.Cells(5, Session2), TripsOffered.Cells(168, Session2))
                    Set TripFind = .Find(what:=TripCal.Cells(TripCounter, "B"), LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
                            If Not TripFind Is Nothing Then
                                Tripdays = TripFind.Offset(0, 4).Value - TripFind.Offset(0, 2).Value
                                    With TripCal.Range(TripCal.Cells(1, 3), TripCal.Cells(1, LastDate))
                                        Set DateFind = .Find(what:=TripFind.Offset(0, 2).Value, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
                                            If Not DateFind Is Nothing Then
                                                For TripDayCount = 0 To Tripdays
                                                    TripCal.Cells(TripCounter, DateFind.Column + TripDayCount) = TripDayCount + 1
                                                Next
                                            Else
                                                MsgBox ("The Trip Date for " & TripFind.Value & " is outside of the current session dates." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please check the trip dates in the 'Trips Being Offered' sheet for " & TripFind.Value & " in Session 2.")
                                            End If
                                    End With
                            End If
            End With
        End If
        TripCounter = TripCounter + 1
    Next

ElseIf TripCal.Range("A1") = "SESSION 3" Then
'the above code repeat depending on Range "A1"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters of the Range.Find Method are optional. But when looking for dates, it is highly recommended to always set the Lookin parameter

```
Set TripFind = .Find(what:=CDate(TripCal.Cells(TripCounter, "B")), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

If you don’t set a Find parameter it uses the existing setting.

Comment: It worked! All I needed to add was the LookIn:=xlFormulas and it now runs on every macro. It is interesting to see the added "CDate" as I don't think I have ever seen that before although I didn't need to add it. The final line of code I ended up using which thus far works fine is:                           
Set DateFind = .Find(what:=TripFind.Offset(0, 2).Value, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

Answer (score 2):

`.Find` looks after the active cell by default - if you change that line to `Set DateFind = .Find(what:=TripFind.Offset(0, 2).Value, After:=TripsOffered.Range(TripsOffered.Cells(5, Session2), LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)`

that'll check all the cells

Comment: Hi @Jeremy, Thank you very much for you speedy response. It is my understanding that while using the 'With' statement above the '.Find' line that I am specifying a range, therefore not resorting to the default. I did however try and add 'After:=Cells(1,1)' and I then came up with a 'Type mismatch (Error 13)'

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I didn't end up trying your edit. I did add 'LookIn:=xlFormulas' as suggested by Docmarti. I did however the first time I tried you suggestion define where to look after more specifically and it also didn't work but I may have been doing something wrong. Thanks again! Keep on Keeping on!